# Inactive threads vs. predicated off threads in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, profiling

I am profiling my CUDA kernel using Visual Profiler 6.0 and on nearly every line there is a bar which shows percentages of `Inactive threads` and `Predicated off threads`.

I was wondering what exactly those two values mean and how 'bad' are they?

As far as I know, the `Inactive threads` (shown in red) are threads that diverged and are inactive (due to some if statement) and `Predicated off threads` (shown in blue) are correctly predicated by compiler to be inactive. Is that correct?

If that is true, I do not understand why following bunch of lines in my kernel has 95% of inactive threads, the only ifs are the loops:

[image: Inactive threads print-screen]

The `TFloat` is template for either `float` or `double` type. What is causing the thread inactivity there?

I am using CUDA 6.0 and the code is running on Tesla K40c under compute capability 3.5.

Comment: I think without knowing the definition of `clustersCount` and `dimensionsCount` it's hard to see if your loops are divergent. Have you tried with the new profiler features in CUDA 7.5 on a Maxwell-based GPU?

Answer (score 3):

From the [following link](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/analysis/report/cudaexperiments/sourcelevel/instructioncount.htm):

> There are two reasons threads within a warp can be disabled: being inactive, and being predicated off. If the block size is not a multiple of the warp size, the last warp in the block will have inactive threads. When some threads within a warp exit the kernel while others continue, the exiting threads become inactive. Threads become predicated off when divergent branches occur, because the separate paths taken by the threads must be serialized, and threads are disabled for paths they do not take.

So it looks like your `dimensionsCount` is zero (or close) on most of the threads, and they exit before a few other threads are still computing.

On the other hand, "predicated off" may be recorded when the the actual branching condition is hit - some thread jump to exit (but still active!), others jump to looping. This is also suggested by the SASS code on the right at your snapshot: the only blue bar appears at `BRA` instruction.

Comment: Small correction, the right snapshot shows SASS (machine code for a specific GPU architecure), not PTX (portable virtual ISA)